# How can I load assembly dynamically thru internet?

Tags: c#, assemblies, c#-2.0, assembly.load

Is there a way or a library that can help me load assembly in memory (dll for example) located on my webpage. I'm trying to figure out a nice crack protection

Comment: This is my fav post of the am.... this sounds like the opposite of protection.

Comment: Why? It's harder to dump the core of the app

Comment: That wouldn't work. Someone can download it and patch it like you do. Your best bet is obfuscation on .NET.

Comment: My idea was the main app, and the dll core that's located on server. Every time the module is loaded in memory, and both of the main and dll are obfuscated.

Comment: how about just using clickonce?

Comment: How does loading an assembly from a web server make it harder to dump core?

Comment: If the main part of the program is located on a remote dll and on bad auth of server it's not loaded (ex: trial expired), I guess it will be harder to dump that dll from memory and patch the application to use it from hard drive.

Comment: Make the core execute on the server — that's the only way you can get real protection.

Comment: It must be executed on client side.

Comment: Then there's no way you can protect it reliably — provided it is useful enough for crackers to devote time to.

Comment: I think obfuscating + this is the best that can be done.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the download, it won't add much to obfuscation and there's extra server traffic to consider as well. Separate obfuscation+watermarking for every client might be a good idea, though.

Comment: Anton knows what he's talking about, once you give code to a client, then all bets are off. DRM/license keys/whatever simply do not work too stop a determined attacker.

Comment: It's fairly simple to set up your own proxy to mimic your server's configuration and behavior. Loading from an external server offers no protection if the execution must be done client-side.

Comment: Yes, but not much people will install a patch that runs proxy on their computer.

Comment: Again it depends on what your program is. Suppose, purely for argument's sake, that it is the much-anticipated game VAPORWARE II — any protection shall be broken as fast as humanly possible, probably within 24 hours of release, and tons of people won't mind installing cracks even if it means turning their machine into a DDOS network bot. OTOH if your program is a new notepad clone, nobody will bother either to crack it or to install cracks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Assembly.Load (byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One could download the file locally, then load it via AssemlblyLoad/reflection....and you would be off to the races. Not sure this is a good idea though.

Comment: Yes, but I want it in memory only.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try..

[C# LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx)

Comment: I guess that can accomplished with downloading in memory and Assembly.Load(byte[])